# TeamCity Artifact Dependencies target directory same source directory

Tags: continuous-integration, sonarqube, teamcity, jacoco

I have 4 teamcity build configuration like this

build, test, static analysis is parallel, sonar wait 3 steps finish and use test results and analysis results for create sonar report.

```
build ------------| 
test -------------|
static analysis --|
                  |----- Sonar report
```

I want use test step results (.exec file for coverage) for sonar step, as I understand, i need use artifact dependencies for this, BUT test step create a many files in build directories like this

/{moduleName}/build/jacoco/*.exec
i have >100 modules

how i can setup artifact dependencies for files transfer to next step without change directory like this -

```
(source dirs)                                (target dirs)
**/build/jacoco/*/*.exec => **/build/jacoco/*/*.exec
```

i can't write this paths in manual

UPD: QUESTION RESOLVED
if use pattern in artifact publish like `+:**/build/jacoco/*/*.exec` (without target), all artifacts save position in directory tree

Comment: Are you using a 3rd party Artifact Repository such as Artifactory? You can easily push the package from each step then bring it down in the last build.